# Fill remaining div height with image

Tags: html, css

I've been doing some googling and I can't find the answer for what I am looking, seemingly simple thing seems to be very complex.

All I want to do is have 2 divs, one should take up as much height as it really needs for rendering.

The second div should fill the remaining space with an image (the image should have height: 100%), eg try to fill the remaining height.

This is where I am currently: http://jsfiddle.net/4rcmnu0z/

I have seen numerous examples how to do this with flexbox and table-row, however they didn't work with image itself.

```
<section>
  <header>
    header: sized to content
      <br/>this height grows as we have more content here.
  </header>
  <div>
    main content: (this fills remaining height) this cat picture should have height 100%<br>
    x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
    <!-- uncomment to see it break -->
    x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
    <!-- -->
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  background: tomato;
}
div {
  flex: 2 ;
  background: gold;
  overflow: auto;

  background-position: center center; 
  background-size:auto 100%; 
  background: url('http://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/featurebox_sidebar_kids/grief-and-loss.jpg') no-repeat;
}
footer {
  background: lightgreen;
  min-height: 60px; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please define the background settings in order. That was the issue, your CSS itself works fine, I made one small change, I set margins for `body` and `html` tag to 0, this removed the scrollbar, you can either use this change or leave it.

Check my below DEMO.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

**CSS:**

```
html, body { height: 100%;margin:0px; }
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  background: tomato;
}
div {
  flex: 2 ;
  background: gold;
  overflow: auto;
  background: url('http://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/featurebox_sidebar_kids/grief-and-loss.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position: center center;
}
footer {
  background: lightgreen;
  min-height: 60px; 
}
```

Comment: goddamnit I spent way too much time on this, cheers! Is there any easy reason why I need to define them in order?

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa The `background` property is used to define all the individual background properties together, in your case, the final command was overriding the other background properties set! Since its used to represent everything together, so the order is very important!

Answer (score 1):

```
html, body { min-height: 100%; }
section {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column;
 height: 100%;
}
header {
 background: tomato;
 flex: 1;
}
div {
 min-height: 100%;
 background: gold;
 overflow: auto;
 background-position: center center; 
 background-size:auto 100%; 
 background:url('http://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/featurebox_sidebar_kids/grief-and-loss.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

Change this with your Css Hope it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply `background-position` and `background-size` after background url. and to stretch image to div make `background-size: cover`.

```
html, body { min-height: 100%; }
section {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column;
 height: 100%;
}
header {
 background: tomato;
 flex: 1;
}
div {
 min-height: 100%;
 background: gold;
 overflow: auto;
 background: url('http://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/featurebox_sidebar_kids/grief-and-loss.jpg') no-repeat;
 background-position: center center; 
 background-size:cover;
}
```

I hope this will work